# Eclipse process sleep on Mac OS X El Capitan beta 3 with JDK 8

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-8

I upgraded my system to OS X El Capitan beta 3 and installed JDK 8 downloaded from Oracle. However, other applications that use JDK is run correctly, only Eclipse Mars stuck on the logo. I checked that stats of Eclipse process. It showed that Eclipse process is sleeping.

Is there any methods to make Eclipse run correctly?  Thanks for any helpful answer.

Comment: Eclipse works again in DP4. Yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reported to Eclipse as high priority bug [472259](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472259). Currently there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in release notes for OS X El Capitan DP3 [1]

> Some versions of Eclipse may hang during use.

See [2] Apple Dev Forums for workaround by reverting back to DP2

[1] https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/rn-osx-10.11/

[2] https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8776

Comment: Not sure. But if public beta is same version as DP3 then yes you should be able to download DP2 and install that to get Eclipse working on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

This bug its already resolved in Beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

According to reports on https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8776#30240 the 4th beta release (public beta 2) fixes the problem. I'm having the same issue but I'm not able to upgrade and test it myself since I'm away from my backup drive for the next few days and I'm not upgrading without that restore point. I'll try to update this with more info once I've tried the upgrade myself.

**Update:** Just upgraded and Eclipse loads without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

there is a makefile that you can use on project to compile and fix this problem.
https://github.com/mnott/javamake

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem of Eclipse not running on El Capitan. It only provides a different way of compiling the code. You're still left without an IDE.